# Why setting percentage padding (and height) dont work in elements inside flexbox in FF

Tags: javascript, flexbox

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4E2bV/793/

```
.imageContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 23%;
    padding-bottom: 23%;
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    margin: 1%;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
body{
    display: flex;
}
```

On FF the items inside body have padding equals 0 - on other browsers it is properly 23% for bottom padding

Is there any workaround to use a percentage values in FF?
On Chrome and IE it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

You fiddle doesn't work on my FF at all. I needed to change it to webkit-flex, like this:

```
body{
   display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

Then it works exactly as in Chrome, no problem with padding.
My FF version: 28.0 
My Chrome ver: 37.0.2062.120 m

Comment: As I wrote - the problem is it's not working in FF - but it works in Chrome. If you change it to -webkit-flex it will be recognized only by Chrome - not by FF - in result it will be display: block (default) on FF. But I need it working with flexbox on FF.

Comment: Your solution just turn on flexbox only on webkit-based browsers

Comment: Yes, I see. And that just turns the flexbox off.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow and don't know what peer review is when editing my own answer... so I give a second one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sorry I misunderstood.
Try NOT to use body as the flex-container. Use a div inside of it instead, surrounding all images. I also altered the css for .imageContainer and .img quite a bit into something I think looks nice. Cute kitties by the way :-)

Here's the code (works both on Chrome and FF):

```
<style>
    .imageContainer{
        /*flex-grow:1;*/
        width:10%;        /*<--- use this to change the image's width */
        margin:1%;
    }
    .cats{
        display: flex;
    }
    img {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<html>
<body>
<div class="cats">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" />
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/302/303" />
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/303/303" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My question was" Is there any workaround to use a **percentage** values in FF?" If I specify .imageContainer height (or padding) in percentages in your example it won't work - in my example it worked (but not on FF)

Comment: Sorry, not that I know off. 
But, if you change the width, to 10% (percent of whole row, not the image), in imageContainer in the solution I gave, you will get the same effect. The images will re-size. Add "justify-content: flex-start" to imageContainer as well to have all the images gather at the left.

Comment: The line that is causing trouble seems to be "position: relative;" this is probably because flex-box is for positioning and then, inside of it you are trying to set new positioning. You can experiment by surrounding each img by a div with display:flex or something similar.

Comment: Yes - width works - but height is not working here :/

Comment: :-) no... but changing the width affects the height as well. And keeping the image ratio while doing that! which is great, I think. Else you would squeeze the pore cats (images). Is this solution not working for you?

Comment: On FF setting `.imageContainer{
        flex-grow:1;
        margin:1%;
        width:0%;
    }` doesn't make any change - nor changes height.

Comment: No, and it won't work at Chrome either because when you set flex-grow:1 you set every flex-item (image) to fill equal amount of space until the whole row's width is filled. Thus your width, which means "0% please if you can" will get ignored. Note that max-width will not get ignored. But maybe mixing both flex-grow and width isn't necessary in your solution, only confusing. Use either or.

Comment: Yes, you are right but still I can't get **height** and vertical padding percentage values working. I'd like to change height independently from width. But thank you for your time and efforts :)

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. If you found my answers useful, up vote or mark as useful.

Comment: Just solved a browser compatibility problem by automatically adding vendor prefixes! Maybe this can help you too. I failed using http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/ which looks very promising, and did it manually using this page: http://pleeease.io/play/